# Android emulator SD card size and file deletion

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I allocated 50MB to the SD card on the emulator and put 2 files in the SD card folder. Now I deleted the files and want to put a new file, but I get a message of no space left. Is there something like a recycle bin on the emulator? How do I delete the files permanently, so I'll be able to use the space they occupied?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya, its happen that emulator memory cleanup is too slow. when we delete something, it doesnt reflect at the same time.

so, *its better to increase your sdcard size at the time of creating emulator.*